# Does LineageOS disable the Android Easter Eggs?

Tags: lineageos, 7.1-nougat, easter-egg

I'm currently running LinageOS 14.1 (Android 7.1), I found a task in Magisk named  `com.android.egg`. It's described as being "Android Easter Egg". Researching it, I found out how to [trigger it here](https://www.pocket-lint.com/apps/news/google/138312-how-to-access-android-easter-egg),

> **Android N "Nougat" easter egg** You can get to the Nougat easter egg in
>   much the same as as Oreo, but the actual game is much more involved.
>   Activate the easter as normal by going into your Settings > About
>   Phone > Android version. Repeatedly tap on the Android Version tab
>   until the "N" appears on screen.
>
> Swipe down from the top of the screen to reveal your quick settings
>   toggles and hit "edit". You should now see a cat face icon with the
>   label, "???? Android Easter egg". Drag and drop this icon to to the
>   main quick settings options and place it where you want it. Now, the
>   fun can begin.
>
> Hit your home button and then drag down the quick settings shade from
>   the top of the screen again. This time you should see an "empty plate"
>   option. Tap it and you'll see an overlay with four food choices: Bits,
>   Fish, Chicken and Treat. Select one, then continue using your phone as
>   normal, and wait.
>
> Eventually, you'll get a notification telling you that a cat has
>   snagged one of the treats. But it doesn't always work, which is kind
>   of the point of the game. You have to keep trying, using different
>   treats to bait a cat.
>
> When it does work, you'll get a notification saying "a cat is here"
>   with the number of the cat listed underneath. Tapping on the
>   notification reveals a new screen with a cat icon which you tap once
>   to rename, or long-press to reveal sharing options. You can save a
>   full resolution version of the cat's picture to your device, or share
>   it to all your social media accounts like every other crazy cat owner.

However, that doesn't work for me. It seems as if on LineageOS the edit option for the drop-down is done by clicking on the pencil at the top. There is no **Edit** text anywhere on the menu. I would still expect that button to work for the purposes of the easter egg?

Does LineageOS disable these Android Easter Eggs? Is it possible to trigger this Easter Egg in LineageOS?

Comment: please try this, pull down notification shade, long press settings icon(gear), and after few seconds, it may show that you have enabled system UI tuner. After, that can you see, edit tiles options.

Comment: @RahulGopi no joy =(

Comment: which device you're using? Is lineage build official? I have done this on my old Redmi 1s Lineage/Cyanogen Nougat build in 2016. So I think, Lineage team don't  disable  this feature that are available on AOSP builds. Also, you can ask about this on XDA forum,  or from where you've downloaded lineage build.

Comment: @RahulGopi system ui tuner is not "activated" in LOS anymore (no such option). Instead, what you usually find in that menu is available in the "normal settings" in places where you'd normally look for it. And I can confirm what Evan wrote: Tapping the Android Version gets you to the N, but the cat is nowhere to be found (official LOS 14.1 ona BQ Aquaris X5 Plus here).

Comment: Weird, I definitely remember seeing that cat easter egg tile in the Edit (pencil) UI. I'll verify on a LOS14.1-running device shortly.